# How to drag slider wpf slower?

Tags: wpf, slider

At the moment, the user can click on the Slider's thumb and move it to the left and to the right in the same speed independent from the mouse cursor's position. I want to update its work, so that the drag speed decreases, when the mouse cursor distance to the Slider increases. That means, when the user drags the Slider's thumb with his mouse and the mouse cursor is over the Slider itself, the drag speed is normal (as it is at the moment). But if he moves the mouse cursor away from the Slider while he is still dragging the Slider's thumb, the drag speed is lower. The further away the mouse cursor is, the lower the drag speed becomes.

Comment: You're making an assumption that all of your users interact with the slider in the same way. This is probably a bad idea. Not everyone will move their mouse away from the slider when interacting with it.

Comment: Thank you! But this is a requirement of my customer. Can you help me? :=)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
 public class YourSlider : Slider
{
    protected override void OnThumbDragDelta(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        // Use distance to modify value change
    }
}
```

And of course you're going to have to calculate where the mouse is, relative to the thumb.

You can work out the thumb using visual.pointtoscreen

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa346961.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

You can use mouse.getposition and visual.pointtoscreen to get the mouse position.